# How to loop ajax post sequentially

Tags: jquery, post, loops

i need to call this post function n-times

```
$.post("prova.php", { myparameter:p1 }, 
    function(msg){ 
       alert('ok')
    }
);
```

so looping it like:

```
for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
   $.post("prova.php", { myparameter:p1 }, 
        function(msg){ 
           updateUI();
        }
    );
}
```

how can i stop other myArray.length -2 $.post when the first is still active? i hope my question is clear.. thanks!!

Comment: put counter , after success again call same function , increment counter ..break when 5 times executed.

Comment: How many times will you be calling `$.post()`. If it's more than 4 you'll probably find the receiving server and/or the browser will throttle your connections. Also, assuming it's name is accurate for it's operation, you'll also only see the result of `updateUI()` from the last AJAX call which completes. I think you may need to rethink what you're trying to do here. Can you not post `myArray` itself in the `data` parameter of the call, so you only need 1 call?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan understood what you say.. i have a div with some rows, every rows is composed by a loading gif and a text. what i need to do is to call that post function in which i do some operation and if result is ok, it will updateUI with response message ( i forgot in my post ). i think this is the unique way to do that. do you think that browser will block me? the server is mine so i can configurate it to allow many post ( are greater then 4 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try that

```
var x = myArray.length;  // n times you want 

function Send (){
  if (x > 0){
     $.post("prova.php", { myparameter:p1 }, 
        function(msg){ 
          x -= 1 ;
          Send();      
        }
     );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
All in one function

var x = myArray.length;  // n times you want

```
function Send (x){
  if (x > 0){
     $.post("prova.php", { myparameter:p1 }, 
        function(msg){ 
          x -= 1 ;
          Send(x);      
        }
     );
  }
}

 function beforeSend(){
    var x = myArray.length;  // n times you want 
    Send (x);
 }
```

Comment: i don't see your previous comment any more but check the update hope it work for you ...

Comment: i delete my comment cause i thought your same solution ;) so it works very good!! thanks so much ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean that you don't want to end up calling the `$.post` requests simultaneously, and you want to wait until the last one finishes before the next one.

You could do this in a ugly way without any external libraries doing something like this:

```
<script src="text/javascript">
var count = 0;

function doRequest()
{
    if (count >= myArray.length)
        return null;

    $.post('prova.php', { myparameter: p1 }, function(msg)
    {
        updateUI();
        count++;
        doRequest();
    });
}

doRequest();
</script>
```

Or you could use one of my favorite javascript libraries, [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).  This allows you to write code that is a little more sane, and easier to follow, and do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
async.whilst(function() //test function, stop running when this is return false
{
    return count < myArray.length;
},
function(callback)
{
    $.post('prova.php', { myparameter: p1 }, function(msg)
    {
        updateUI();         
        count++;
        callback(null); //callback with null as the error
    });
},
function(error) //this is called when we're done
{
    //do stuff
});
</script>
```

Either of those two functions should handle just doing a single request at a time for you, assuming that's what you want.